# write sql queries using jquery for a ruby application

Tags: jquery

I have a ruby on rails application.I am using jquery to populate a drop down list box.
I have to get the values from the sql query.
i.e selected_release=Release.find(id)
cycles=selected_release.cycles.
The second drop down is populated from cycles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't create a sql like query within jQuery if I was you.

How about creating a onchange event on the first dropdown, which wil post the Id of the Release to an action, which renders the cycles dropdown?

see [this link](http://pullmonkey.com/2008/03/30/dynamic-select-boxes-ruby-on-rails/) for an example

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for your suggestion.Could you please explain me like how to populate the drop down with the results that i got in the controller using jquery

Comment: see the example in my answer :)

Comment: Hi Manuel,Thanks a lot for ur help.I went through the example.I am getting the following error "RJS error.Object doesn't support this property or method.I have posted the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817382/rjs-error-object-doesnt-support-this-property-on-element-update